# Sails nested model collection

Tags: mysql, orm, coffeescript, sails.js

i have 3 models.

User model:

```
module.exports =
  schema: true
  attributes:
    login:
      type: 'string'
      required: true
    hosts:
      collection: 'host'
      via: 'owners'
    accounts:
      collection: 'account'
      via: 'users'
```

Host model:

```
module.exports =

  attributes:
    url:
      type: 'string'
      required: true
      unique: true
    owners:
      collection: 'user'
      via: 'hosts'
    accounts:
      collection: 'account'
      via: 'host'
```

Account model:

```
module.exports =

  attributes:
    provider:
      type: 'string'
      required: true
    password:
      type: 'string'
    users:
      collection: 'user'
      via: 'accounts'
    host:
      model: 'host'
```

And i whant found all Users hosts with accounts. How do it?

This option works but I'm not sure that he's good, I'll be very grateful if you tell how to do differently. Or maybe change something in my version.

```
User
.findOne(id)
.populate('hosts')
.then (hosts) ->
  hostsObj = []
  for host in hosts.hosts
    accounts = Host
    .find(host.id)
    .populate('accounts')
    .then (account) ->
      hostsObj.push(account[0])
      return account
  return [hostsObj,accounts]
.spread (hostsObj, accounts) ->
  done(null, hostsObj)
.catch (err) ->
  return done('Not hosts') if err
```