# Sails collection searching

Tags: javascript, model, sails.js

Similar to [Sails nested model collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342375/sails-nested-model-collection) but that was never answered

I have 2 models that I wish to get data from easily. I am given the player and from then I must list the permissions that rank has.
I currently looking for an alternative for .native() and .query() because they force me to be database specific.

```
/**
* Player.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    // SteamId of the user used as primary key
    steam_id: {
      type: 'string',
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },

    // The steam name of the player
    steam_name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    // A friendly name (RPname etc)
    friendly_name: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    servers:{
      collection: 'Server',
      via: 'players'
    },

    // The rank of the user (Admin, user, etc)
    ranks:{
      collection:'Rank',
      via: 'players',
      required: true
    },

    // List of their punishments (This includes warns)
    punishments: {
      collection: 'Punishment',
      via: 'victim'
    },

    notes: {
      collection: 'Note',
      via: 'player'
    }

  }
};
```

And the rank

```
/**
* Rank.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {


    name:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    players:{
      collection: 'Player',
      via: 'ranks',
    },

    permissions:{
      collection: 'Permission',
      via: 'rank'
    },

    server:{
      model: 'Server',
      required: true
    }

  }
};
```

The only way I can think of doing it is similar to this.

```
Player.findOne(Player).populate('ranks').exec(function(err, player){
    player.ranks.forEach(function(err, rank){
        Rank.findOne(rank).populate('permissions', {Command:1}).exec(function(error, rank){
            // What I want
            rank.permissions;
        });
    });
});
```

Which is overly cumbersome. Could you please give some tips on how to make it more efficient or effective?

I'd like to do something like

```
Rank.findOne().where({server:1,players:{contains:player}}).populate('permissions').exec(function(err, rank){
    //What I want
    rank.permissions
});
```